# can't display json data on bar chart 24h x axis d3 js

Tags: json, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to display json data which I get from a php script that fetches the data from a database.
I'm only interested in the time (called vrijeme in the script) which for instance looks like this:

```
data[0].vrijeme
//output: 00:09:27
```

Now I'm trying to get this time data on my x axis so I can create a bar chart.
The x axis has a 24h domain and a bar should be created depending on the data[i].vrijeme value. So if the value is 00:09:27 a bar on the graph should be created at that specific time.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way.

Could someone please look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
I'm new to d3.js and I'm struggling with it.
I keep getting this error in the firefox console:

```
uncaught exception: out of memory <unknown>
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.min.js:3:9846
Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute. d3.min.js:1:0
Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute. d3.min.js:1:0
```

And this error in the chrome console:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
```

Here is the js part:

```
    var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 40
},
width = 800,
    height = 500;


var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
todayMillis = today.getTime();

d3.json("getDataFromDB.php", function(error, data) {

   var i = 0;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        var parser = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S");


        var dejt = parser.parse(data[i].vrijeme);


        i++;
        var timePeriodMillis = (parseInt(dejt.getHours(), 10) * 60 * 60 * 1000) +
                               (parseInt(dejt.getMinutes(), 10) * 60 * 1000) + 
                               (parseInt(dejt.getSeconds(), 10) * 1000);

        d.time = new Date();
        d.time.setTime(todayMillis + timePeriodMillis);
    });


var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }))
    .nice(d3.time.day, 1)
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 2])
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 2)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(8);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .tickPadding(8)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
    return '';
});

var svg = d3.select('#bar-chart').append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

svg.selectAll('.chart')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return x(d.time);
    })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
        return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - (height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y(d.total))
    })
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('height', function (d) {
        return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y(d.total)
    });

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", -25)
    .attr("y", 430)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Off");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", -25)
    .attr("y", 220)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("On");

    });
```

I apologize for the messy code.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong... I didn't pass the height value from the json data. I have to replace the parts: y(d.total) with y(d.stanje)

Comment: Answer your question with correct data if you found the error to help other people may have same problem.